# Como obtener una foto sacada de la Cam para guardarla con MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fileupload

Tengo un codigo que saca la foto activando la camara del pc, la encripta pasandola a base64:

```
    <video id="video"></video>
    <br>
    <button id="boton">Tomar foto</button>
    <p id="estado"></p>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="display: none;"></canvas>
    <script>

        function tieneSoporteUserMedia() {
            return !!(navigator.getUserMedia || (navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia)
        }
        function _getUserMedia() {
            return (navigator.getUserMedia || (navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia).apply(navigator, arguments);
        }

        // Declaramos elementos del DOM
        var $video = document.getElementById("video"),
            $canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            $boton = document.getElementById("boton"),
            $estado = document.getElementById("estado");
        if (tieneSoporteUserMedia()) {
            _getUserMedia(
                { video: true },
                function (stream) {
                    console.log("Permiso concedido");
                    $video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    $video.play();

                    //Escuchar el click
                    $boton.addEventListener("click", function () {

                        //Pausar reproducción
                        $video.pause();

                        //Obtener contexto del canvas y dibujar sobre él
                        var contexto = $canvas.getContext("2d");
                        $canvas.width = $video.videoWidth;
                        $canvas.height = $video.videoHeight;
                        contexto.drawImage($video, 0, 0, $canvas.width, $canvas.height);

                        var foto = $canvas.toDataURL(); //Esta es la foto, en base 64
                        $estado.innerHTML = "Enviando foto. Por favor, espera...";
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.open("POST", "GuardarFoto", true);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        xhr.send("archivo=" + encodeURIComponent(foto)); //Codificar y enviar

                        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                            if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
                                console.log("La foto fue enviada correctamente");
                                console.log(xhr);
                                $estado.innerHTML = "Foto guardada con éxito. Puedes verla <a target='_blank' href='./" + xhr.responseText + "'> aquí</a>";
                            }
                        }

                        //Reanudar reproducción
                        $video.play();
                    });
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log("Permiso denegado o error: ", error);
                    $estado.innerHTML = "No se puede acceder a la cámara, o no diste permiso.";
                });
        } else {
            alert("Lo siento. Tu navegador no soporta esta característica");
            $estado.innerHTML = "Parece que tu navegador no soporta esta característica. Intenta actualizarlo.";
        }
    </script>
```

EN el controller deseo recibirla usando Request.File, y no por parametro en el que tenga que desincreptar de base64. La forma que trato de hacerlo es así:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GuardarFoto()
        {


            //string temp = Server.UrlDecode(Request.Form["archivo"]).Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
            //byte[] arr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Base64Decode(temp));

            //String Foldername_0 = Server.MapPath("~/Fotos/");

            //System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Foldername_0 +"Fotocam.png", arr);

            for (int j = 0; j < Request.Files.Count; j++)
            {
                var fileuploader = Request.Files[j];
                if (fileuploader.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    string Foldername;
                    string Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileuploader.FileName);
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploader.FileName.ToString());
                    if (Extension == ".png" || Extension == ".jpg" || Extension == ".jpeg" || Extension == ".JPG")
                    {

                        Foldername = Server.MapPath("~/Fotos/");
                        fileuploader.SaveAs(Foldername + filename.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            return Json(new { responseText = "Fotos/Fotocam.png" });
        }
```

Pero al pasar por el ciclo for del controller no entra porque no captura el archivo.
Me gustaría saber como puedo enviar la foto desde la vista al controller.
Trate de hacerlo de esta forma, pero tampoco resulto:

```
 <script>

        function tieneSoporteUserMedia() {
            return !!(navigator.getUserMedia || (navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia)
        }
        function _getUserMedia() {
            return (navigator.getUserMedia || (navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia).apply(navigator, arguments);
        }

        // Declaramos elementos del DOM
        var $video = document.getElementById("video"),
            $canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            $boton = document.getElementById("boton"),
            $estado = document.getElementById("estado");
        if (tieneSoporteUserMedia()) {
            _getUserMedia(
                { video: true },
                function (stream) {
                    console.log("Permiso concedido");
                    $video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    $video.play();

                    //Escuchar el click
                    $boton.addEventListener("click", function () {

                        //Pausar reproducción
                        $video.pause();

                        //Obtener contexto del canvas y dibujar sobre él
                        var contexto = $canvas.getContext("2d");
                        $canvas.width = $video.videoWidth;
                        $canvas.height = $video.videoHeight;
                        contexto.drawImage($video, 0, 0, $canvas.width, $canvas.height);
                        var cam = $canvas;
                        $estado.innerHTML = "Enviando foto. Por favor, espera...";
                        debugger;
                        //if ($canvas.length > 0) {
                                var data = new FormData();
                                for (var x = 0; x < cam.length; x++) {
                                    debugger;
                                    data.append("file" + x, $canvas.files[x]);
                                }

                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: '/Cam/GuardarFoto',
                                    contentType: false,
                                    processData: false,
                                    data: data,
                                    success: function (result) {
                                        console.log(result);
                                    },
                                    error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                                        var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
                                        if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                                            err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
                                        console.log(err);
                                    }
                                });

                        //}
                        //var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        //xhr.open("POST", "GuardarFoto", true);
                        //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        //xhr.send("archivo=" + encodeURIComponent(foto)); //Codificar y enviar

                        //xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        //    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
                        //        console.log("La foto fue enviada correctamente");
                        //        console.log(xhr);
                        //        $estado.innerHTML = "Foto guardada con éxito. Puedes verla <a target='_blank' href='./" + xhr.responseText + "'> aquí</a>";
                        //    }
                        //}

                        //Reanudar reproducción
                        $video.play();
                    });
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log("Permiso denegado o error: ", error);
                    $estado.innerHTML = "No se puede acceder a la cámara, o no diste permiso.";
                });
        } else {
            alert("Lo siento. Tu navegador no soporta esta característica");
            $estado.innerHTML = "Parece que tu navegador no soporta esta característica. Intenta actualizarlo.";
        }
    </script>
```

Si alguien tiene alguna idea, desde ya, le agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 no es un archivo, sino un string, por lo que la propiedad `Request.Files` nunca tendrá datos.

Tendras que obtener el string base64 del `Request` que es por donde la estas enviando con el nombre de `archivo`:

```
string base64File = Request["archivo"];
byte[] bytesFoto = Convert.FromBase64String(base64File);
// procedes a guardar los bytes del archivo
```

Comment: Además, Base64 no es un tipo de encripción, sino una manera para hacer transmitiendo datos más fácil.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solución, la publicaré si  ha alguien le sirve.
Primero debo hacer una conversión antes:

```
                    var blobBin = atob(foto.split(',')[1]);
                    var array = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < blobBin.length; i++) {
                        array.push(blobBin.charCodeAt(i));
                    }
                    var file = new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], { type: 'image/png' });
                    var formdata = new FormData();
                    formdata.append("file", file);
```

Así queda:

```
 function tieneSoporteUserMedia() {
            return !!(navigator.getUserMedia || (navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia)
        }
        function _getUserMedia() {
            return (navigator.getUserMedia || (navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia).apply(navigator, arguments);
        }

        // Declaramos elementos del DOM
        var $video = document.getElementById("video"),
            $canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            $boton = document.getElementById("boton"),
            $estado = document.getElementById("estado");
        if (tieneSoporteUserMedia()) {
            _getUserMedia(
                { video: true },
                function (stream) {
                    console.log("Permiso concedido");
                    $video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    $video.play();

                    //Escuchar el click
                    $boton.addEventListener("click", function () {

                        //Pausar reproducción
                        $video.pause();

                        //Obtener contexto del canvas y dibujar sobre él
                        var contexto = $canvas.getContext("2d");
                        $canvas.width = $video.videoWidth;
                        $canvas.height = $video.videoHeight;
                        contexto.drawImage($video, 0, 0, $canvas.width, $canvas.height);

                        var foto = $canvas.toDataURL(); //Esta es la foto, en base 64
                        //$estado.innerHTML = "Enviando foto. Por favor, espera...";
                        //var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        //xhr.open("POST", "GuardarFoto", true);
                        //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        //xhr.send("archivo=" + encodeURIComponent(foto)); //Codificar y enviar
                        debugger;
                        var blobBin = atob(foto.split(',')[1]);
                        var array = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < blobBin.length; i++) {
                            array.push(blobBin.charCodeAt(i));
                        }
                        var file = new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], { type: 'image/png' });
                        var formdata = new FormData();
                        formdata.append("file", file);


                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '/Cam/GuardarFoto',
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false,
                            data: formdata,
                            success: function (result) {
                                console.log(result);
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                                var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
                                if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                                    err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                        });
                        //xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        //    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
                        //        console.log("La foto fue enviada correctamente");
                        //        console.log(xhr);
                        //        $estado.innerHTML = "Foto guardada con éxito. Puedes verla <a target='_blank' href='./" + xhr.responseText + "'> aquí</a>";
                        //    }
                        //}

                        //Reanudar reproducción
                        $video.play();
                    });
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log("Permiso denegado o error: ", error);
                    $estado.innerHTML = "No se puede acceder a la cámara, o no diste permiso.";
                });
        } else {
            alert("Lo siento. Tu navegador no soporta esta característica");
            $estado.innerHTML = "Parece que tu navegador no soporta esta característica. Intenta actualizarlo.";
        }
```